# Как в Postman или SoupUI перенести данные из тела ответа в headers всех следующих запросов?

Tags: rest, token, postman

Проблема такова: раз в 24 часа обновляется токен для доступа к API. Получается новый токен POST запросом по логину/паролю. Приходит в теле ответа. Для дальнейшей работы нужно использовать полученный код/токен в headers каждого следующего запроса. Не могу понять как это осуществить. Создать переменную? Но как автоматически ее изменять, как засунуть ее в headers?